# Scroll Views, Zooming and Zoom Origin Confusion

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I've been reading through quite a bit of documentation, and I must say, I'm quite confused.  Here is what I have currently have setup.

In an iPad project, I have a UIScrollView (`scrollView`) that contains a child UIView (`insetView`).  My `insetView` is returned from the `scrollViewDidEndZooming` method and is used strictly for zooming it's child views.

`insetView` starts out smaller than and centered on `scrollView`.  As the user pinches to Zoom, `insetView` can either grow to twice it's original size, or shrink to half of it's original size.

All of this works fine but there is one little annoyance that I want to alleviate.  If I pinch to zoom, `insetView` shrinks, but the origin of the zooming is the top-left corner of `insetView`.  In other words, `insetView` will both grow and shrink with it's top-left point fixed in the `scrollView` window.

What I would like to do is have `insetView` zoom in and out on it's center, and stay fixed at the center of `scrollView` until it is sized larger than the `scrollView` area. At that point, I would like for the zoom origin to be the middle of the pinch or, at least, at the center of the current portion of `insetView` that is currently visible?

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do something like this in your `scrollViewDidZoom:` delegate method:

```
CGSize boundsSize = scrollView.bounds.size;
CGRect frameToCenter = insetView.frame;

if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
    frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2.0f;
} else {
    frameToCenter.origin.x = 0.0f;
}

if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
    frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2.0f;
} else {
    frameToCenter.origin.y = 0.0f;
}

insetView.frame = frameToCenter;
```

Comment: If my `scrollView` is not the same size as my display, shouldn't the `CGSize boundsSize = self.bounds.size;` line read `CGSize boundsSize = scrollView.bounds.size;`?

Comment: Apologies, yes it should. I copied the code from a project of mine and edited it, but failed to edit that bit correctly. Well spotted. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!  I actually had this in my code at one point except for the `else` statements.  That was a missing part of what my code was doing, and the bug that came without that code was more annoying than the behavior outlined above.  I'm marking this as the answer, but I do have one more question.  My `insetView` still remained fixed in `scrollView` by it's top-left corner, while pinching.  The display is re-centered when I release the pinch.  Is there a way to do this, while zooming is taking affect, or will I just need to live with it?  This works, but I'm picky and like app polish! :)

Comment: Hmm, I remember something about this with iOS 5 being a slight problem, but I really did think `scrollViewDidZoom:` was called constantly throughout the zoom process and so it worked. Can you check that it is being called whilst zooming?

Comment: No, it's not executing.  I could be missing something (I'm quite new to XCode and OSX/iOS development.)  My delegates signature is `-(void) scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView*)sc withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale`.  Should I be defining some other delegate?

Comment: Implement the `scrollViewDidZoom:` method as well and put my code in there.